# Configuring Kubernetes Pet Set with NFS

Tags: kubernetes, stateful

I am trying to configure [Pet Set](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/) in Kubernetes 1.3. There is a NFS storage backend that works as expected with Persistent Volumes, Claims, and Pods. However, when I create a Pet Set the VolumeClaimTemplate is never bound to the Persistent Volume backed by NFS.

Below is the definition of the PV -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: janipv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  nfs:
    path: /var/data/test
    server: 172.17.4.101
```

When I try running the [Pet Set sample](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/release-1.3/docs/user-guide/petset.yaml) available in the documentation, I see the following message.

```
kubelet describe pv

{persistentvolume-controller }          Warning         ProvisioningFailed      No provisioner plugin found for the claim!
```

The same configuration works fine when I use normal Pod instead of a Pet Set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have an NFS dynamic provisioner, like the error indicates: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/#alpha-limitations (unless you wrote one, in which case we can start debugging). The volumeclaimtemplate itself never gets bound to anything. It's a template for the creation of volume claims, i.e the controller will create pvc-0, pvc-1... for pet-0,pet-1... those claims are bound to persistent volumes through a dynamic volume provisioner (as opposed to a static volume provisioning process where a human creates the pv and attaches it to the pvc).

You can hand attach an existing pv to one of the petset claims, just like you would for a replication controller's pods, by setting the volumeName field of the pvc.

Comment: Thanks Prashanth! I have three questions -

1) Does that mean If I create a PVC  before hand with the naming convention of PVC-0 to PVC-n, it will be bound by controller at runtime?

2) During the alpha, which dynamic provisioner is supported?

3) If I use hostPath pointing to a NFS share, do I get the expected outcome with Pet Set?

Comment: No only the pvc is created for you. Binding is the job of the provisioner (which doesn't exist in your case, so provisioner == human). If you're on a cloud provider, the right provisioner should be started for you, if you're on metal, you need to start one (I believe ceph and gluster are in the works: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/30888,  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/31251).